# Which persistence plugins are supported by akka-typed & cluster sharding

Tags: akka, event-sourcing, akka-cluster, akka-persistence, akka-typed

I'm playing around with Akka Typed (version 2.6.0) & event sourcing, and I was able to make it work with LevelDB plugin.

Since I intend to use a cluster environment, LevelDB wouldn't work on such setup, since it storages data on local file system, as it's pointed here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence-plugins.html

I tried to use cassandra plugin, but it seems not be compatible with Akka 2.6.X

Is there any persistence plugin compatible with Akka Typed 2.6.X and useful in a cluster environment setup currently?

Answer (score 2):

Since we keep binary compatibility between Akka minor versions all the persistence plugins that work for Akka 2.5 should work with 2.6.

For the Cassandra plugin we actually test against 2.6 in our CI jobs - see https://travis-ci.org/akka/akka-persistence-cassandra/jobs/633761567

Note however if the plugin has a dependency for Akka 2.5 modules you will have to override each of those to be 2.6 so that you don't get mixed module versions on the classpath. Akka promises binary compatibility for the public APIs but not for the internal APIs that the modules of Akka share with each other.